# Select dates, wrap in quotation marks and concatenate

Tags: mysql

I'd like to get this:

```
'27.11.2019', '26.11.2019', '23.11.2019', '22.11.2019', '21.11.2019'
```

Table:

[image]

My code (only unique values are necessary):

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT quote(DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d.%m.%Y')), ", ") from wp_ved_currencies order by date desc limit 5
```

The result of execution:

```
'26.11.2019', ,'23.11.2019', ,'22.11.2019', ,'27.11.2019', ,'30.12.2017', ,'10.01.2018', ,'11.01.2018', ,'12.01.2018', ,'13.01.2018', ,'16.01.2018', ,'17.01.2018', ,'18.01.2018', ,'19.01.2018', ,'20.01.2018', ,'23.01.2018', ,'24.01.2018', ,'25.01.2018', ,'26.01.2018', ,'27.01.2018', ,'30.01.2018', ,'31.01.2018', ,'01.02.2018', ,'02.02.2018', ,'03.02.2018', ,'06.02.2018', ,'07.02.2018', ,'08.02.2018', ,'09.02.2018', ,'10.02.2018', ,'13.02.2018', ,'14.02.2018', ,'15.02.2018', ,'16.02.2018', ,'17.02.2018', ,'20.02.2018', ,'21.02.2018', ,'22.02.2018', ,'23.02.2018', ,'27.02.2018', ,'28.02.2018', ,'01.03.2018', ,'02.03.2018', ,'03.03.2018', ,'06.03.2018', ,'07.03.2018', ,'08.03.2018', ,'13.03.2018', ,'14.03.2018', ,'15.03.2018', ,'16.03.2018', ,'17.03.2018', ,'20.03.2018', ,'21.03.2018', ,'22.03.2018', ,'23.03.2018', ,'24.03.2018', ,'27.03.2018', ,'28.03.2018', ,'29.03.2018', ,'30.03.2018', ,'31.03.2018', ,'03.04.2018', ,'04.04.2018', ,'05.04.2018', ,'06.04.2018', ,'07.04.2018', ,'10.04.2018', ,'11.04.2018', ,'12.
```

Well, strange result: no limitation, double comma, no order. Could you help me?

Comment: I did posted a answer which might give you the correct answer. But see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Well, strange result: no limitation, double comma, no order. Could you
>   help me?

i believe you are looking for

```
SELECT 
 GROUP_CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d.%m.%Y') ORDER BY date ASC/DESC)
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT date FROM wp_ved_currencies  order by date desc limit 5
) AS alias
```

instead of

```
select
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT quote(DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d.%m.%Y')), ", ")
from wp_ved_currencies order by date desc limit 5
```

Comment: The distinct would go inside the subquery if you go the LIMIT way.

Answer (score 0):

select
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT quote(DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d.%m.%Y')), ", ")
from wp_ved_currencies order by date desc limit 5

```
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(
           DISTINCT
           QUOTE(DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d.%m.%Y'))
           ORDER BY date
           SEPARATOR ', ')
    FROM wp_ved_currencies;
```

Unfortunately, there is no `LIMIT` clause (yet) in `GROUP_CONCAT`.  There are two solutions:

```
 SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(...), ',', 5)
```

The more complex is

```
 SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(..without DISTINCT..)
     FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT date
                ... LIMIT 5 ) AS x
```

`ORDER BY date` show up twice.